# Unwanted parameters in URL after s:link and f:param

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, seam

Here is the code (Seam 2, JSF 1.2)

```
<s:link style="color: white;" value="Full Listing "
    rendered="#{not listControl.fullList}"
    action="#{listControl.setFullList(true)}" >
    <f:param name="maxResults" value="" />
    <f:param name="firstResult" value="" />
</s:link>

<s:link style="color: white;" value="Limited Listing "
    rendered="#{listControl.fullList}" 
    action="#{listControl.setFullList(false)}" >
    <f:param name="maxResults" value="#{entityMaxResult}" />
    <f:param name="firstResult" value="" />
</s:link>
```

The goal is to use this link to toggle between a results listing displayin maxResults and all results.

The original URL is this

```
_http://localhost:8080/ond/ONDList.seam?maxResults=2&state=DE
```

When I click the link I get the correct functionality, but the resulting URL is this

```
_http://localhost:8080/ond/ONDList.seam?state=DE&actionMethod=pages%2Flist%2FONDList.xhtml%3AlistControl.setFullList%28true%29
```

And I click again I get

```
_http://localhost:8080/ond/ONDList.seam?maxResults=2&state=DE&actionMethod=pages%2Flist%2FONDList.xhtml%3AlistControl.setFullList%28false%29
```

What I was ***expecting*** to get was simply these 2 URLs:

```
_http://localhost:8080/ond/ONDList.seam?maxResults=15&firstResult=0&state=AL
```

and

```
_http://localhost:8080/ond/ONDList.seam?state=AL
```

Where do the extra parameters on those URLs come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `s:link` is using *http GET* and not *http POST*, then seam needs to somehow know which action to invoke. Thus it appends the action in the request parameter.

If you want to avoid seeing anything in the request parameter, then you have to use a link that produces *http post* such as `<h:commandLink>`

However, I don't see any reason why you would want to hide the action. 
If you are afraid of request forgery you can enforce the action by using the `@Restrict` or `@Permission` annotation on the component or method.

Comment: OK, this is making some sense.  I think one thing I have a very fundamental problem is is fully understanding the difference between an POST and a GET.  It seems that with a POST none of the information you pass shows on the URL and with a GET, ALL of the information you pass must show on the URL.  You have to use workarounds like URL rewrite filtering to only show SOME of the info on the URL.  Armed with this information I will toy with this some more.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes you have to understand the difference here. Read more about it by googling http post and http get

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Because you have an action parameter in s:seam. The action will be executed in backend, and then page navigation rules will be evaluated.

Maybe you want to use a h:outputLink?

Answer (score 0):

You may use URL rewrite filter to make URLs look nicer.